# Windows batch script: trying to extract Java version by looping on command results with pipe

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd, delayedvariableexpansion

I want to extract the Java version on my machine.
1/ I have an Oracle Java 8 installed and the command `where java` outputs this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
```

2/ The command `java -version` outputs this:

```
java version "1.8.0_221"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_221-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.221-b11, mixed mode)
```

3/ The command `java -version 2>&1 | find "version"` outputs this:

```
java version "1.8.0_221"
```

So I want to do the exact same thing as the last command within a batch file. So within a batch file, I have this code similar to step 2:

```
@echo off & setLocal enableExtensions enableDelayedExpansion
set /a count=0
for /f "tokens=*" %%j in ('where java') do (
    set /a count+=1
    set JAVA[!count!]=%%j
    call :echo_java
)
goto :eof

:echo_java
    set java_cmd="!JAVA[%count%]!" -version
    for /f "tokens=*" %%v in ('%java_cmd% 2^>^&1') do echo %%v
    exit /b 0
```

But as soon as I modify the function `:echo_java` to be the equivalent to step 3 like this:

```
:echo_java
    set java_cmd="!JAVA[%count%]!" -version
    for /f "tokens=*" %%v in ('%java_cmd% 2^>^&1 ^| find "version"') do echo %%v
    exit /b 0
```

I get this error:

```
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I suppose that there are some bad escaping happening here but I really can't see what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After variable expansion the line:

```cmd
for /f "tokens=*" %%v in ('%java_cmd% 2^>^&1 ^| find "version"') do echo %%v
```

expands to something like:

```cmd
for /f "tokens=*" %%v in ('"C:\Program Files (x86)\...\java.exe" 2^>^&1 ^| find "version"') do echo %%v
```

so the command line to be executed by `for /F` begins and ends with `"`.

`for /F` uses `cmd /c` to execute that command line, which removes the surrounding `"`, thus leaving this behind:

```cmd
C:\Program Files (x86)\...\java.exe" 2>&1 | find "version
```

which is obviously incorrect syntax.

To avoid that, change the command line so that it is not surrounded by quotation marks (by moving the redirection portion here):

```cmd
for /f "tokens=*" %%v in ('2^>^&1 %java_cmd% ^| find "version"') do echo %%v
```

Alternatively, provide explicit quotation marks that can be removed by `cmd /C`, so the remainder stays valid (escape these quotes in order not to have to alter other escape sequences):

```cmd
for /f "tokens=*" %%v in ('^"%java_cmd% 2^>^&1 ^| find "version"^"') do echo %%v
```

---

Furthermore, I would like to suggest to modify the whole script a bit (see all the `rem` remarks):

```cmd
@echo off
rem /* Begin the script with delayed expansion disabled as it might lead to problems
rem    during expansion of `for` meta-variables in case the values contain `!`: */
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
rem // Use quoted `set` syntax (this requires the command extensions to be enabled):
set /A "count=0"
for /F "tokens=*" %%j in ('where java') do (
    set /A "count+=1"
    rem // Enable delayed expansion only when needed, like for variable `count` here:
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem /* (Mis-)use a `for` loop to make the value of `!count!` available even when
    rem    delayed expansion is disabled, hence after `endlocal` then: */
    for %%c in (!count!) do endlocal & set "JAVA[%%c]=%%j"
    rem /* Pass an argument over to the sub-routine rather than using variables
    rem    globally; in this situation this even does not need delayed expansion: */
    call :ECHO_JAVA "%%j"
)
endlocal
goto :EOF

:ECHO_JAVA
    rem /* Explicitly disable delayed expansion in the sub-routine, so you may call
    rem    it even from a code section with delayed expansion enabled: */
    setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
    rem /* Use the sub-routine argument (`%~1`) herein, with explicit control of
    rem    quotation (`~` removes potential quotes, then we explicitly add such): */
    for /F "tokens=*" %%v in ('2^>^&1 "%~1" -version ^| find "version"') do echo(%%v
    endlocal
    exit /B 0
```

Comment: I can't believe that this kind of quirks do happen in Windows batch scripting... I also didn't know you could reverse the positions of the command and the redirection portions to the same results. Thanks a bunch!