# multiple quotation marks in for loop (batch file)

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, double-quotes, quoting

Having a batch file that uses 7-Zip to "look" into a zip-file if it contains a certain file.

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" l "FolderName\archive.zip" "file.cmd"
```

But putting it into a for-loop it produces the error: 'cannot find "C:\Program" '. Writing %ProgramFiles% also makes no difference.

```
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" l "FolderName\archive.zip" "file.cmd"') do ...
```

However, it works if I omit the quotation around the zip-file and the file that is searched.

```
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" l FolderName\archive.zip file.cmd') do ...
```

Finally I found a solution to put the command in a variable and place it into the for loop.

```
set command="C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" l "FolderName\archive.zip" "file.cmd"
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('"%command%"') do ...
```

The variable still requires quotation marks. I'd like to understand how that works. How can I have multiple quoted strings that are placed in a quoted variable but cannot pass them directly to the for loop.

It seems to be a similar problem as the operators like &, >, |, ... that need escaping with ^. I tried that too, but with no success. It kept me asking: "more?" thus the closing bracket wasn't found anymore.

Comment: Related: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60749390)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you actually answered your own question without looking closely.
Let me show you why:

```
set command="C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" l "FolderName\archive.zip" "file.cmd"
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('"%command%"') do ...
```

Note that your code translates the value of the `set` command to:

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" l "FolderName\archive.zip" "file.cmd"
```

where you then pass that to the loop in double quotes again, as:

```
"%command%"
```

which ends up being:

```
""C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" l "FolderName\archive.zip" "file.cmd""
```

Which will work exactly in a for loop:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('""C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" l "FolderName\archive.zip" "file.cmd""') do ...
```

Though that will work as expected in this case, it will fail if your quoted strings contain special characters like `&` as shown in this example:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('""C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" l "FolderName\archives & backups.zip" "file.cmd""') do ...
```

So you need to simply escape the outer double quotes to overcome this:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('^""C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" l "FolderName\archives & backups.zip" "file.cmd"^"') do ...
```

Point 2. from `cmd /?` seemingly states this behaviour, as per the below screenshot:
[image]

Comment: It certainly seems odd, but is reproducible. I've never encountered the problem, but I've also never used the `for...('"exename"...` format. I simply put `7z.exe` and `7z.dll` into my `\batch` directory, and *that* on my `path`. Possibly need to keep this in mind for other quoted full-pathnames in this position.

Comment: @Magoo, indeed. However it is documented (sort off). When running `cmd /?` and you scroll to the section just below `If /C or /K is specified..` point `2.` states: `Otherwise, old behavior is to see if the first character is a quote character and if so, strip the leading character and remove the last quote character on the command line, preserving any text after the last quote character`

Comment: Uh.. I've posted a screenshot to the answer instead @Magoo.

Comment: Yes, I had the 7z in my %path% but this didn't apply to all systems where this is used.
It just looks so wrong to have ""path1" "path2"". I would expect three strings, "", " ", "" and two unknown-command-errors: path1 and path2.